# Rococo Parathread / Parachain -> Slot Rotation still working?

Tags: rococo, parathread, slot

i am proud owner of a rococo Parathread with the ID 3025 - once there was the slot rotation and from time to time ( 3 days interval ) the parathread became a parachain. I am wondering if there is a problem or anything has changed. The parathread hasn't been upgraded for while now.
Thx in advance.
tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be working but just in case we assigned you again a temporary slot.

Let us know if you see this issue again. We will be attentive.

Comment: Thanks indeed for the quick reply.

Comment: Thx - the parathread was upgraded now.